# Why map in js doesn't accept function argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, array-map

I was calling a function and pass array of objects as first argument and second argument was object property of first argument but I don't know why map func doesn't accepting second argument property
Here code plz see it once

```
const myfunc = (arrObj, property) => {
  const arr1 = arrObj.map(item => {
    return item.property
  }
  return arr1:
}

const arrObj = [{
    title: 'book',
    body: 'hello'
  },
  {
    title: 'cup',
    body: 'hii'
  }
];

// Func call
console.log(myfunc(arrObj, 'title'));
```

Comment: You should be using lowercase `const` and `return`. But the key problem is you're not actually returning anything from `myfunc` to log.

Comment: Please fix the casing of your code (JavaScript is case-sensitive and `const`/`return` are lowercase) and the syntax error(s) (your `console.log` line is missing a parenthesis). Also please add what exactly you expect this code to do.

Comment: You also need to access the property with `item[property]` otherwise it is just looking for a property called `property`

Answer (score 3):

1. Use lowercase for `const`, `return`, `console`.
2. Return a value (an array, in this case) from your function that you can log.
3. Use `item[property]` to access the title property. There is no "property" key in those objects.
4. Make sure you close all of your parentheses.

```js
function myfunc(arrObj, property) {
  return arrObj.map(item => item[property]);
}

const arrObj=[{title:"book",body:"hello"},{title:"cup",body:"hii"}];

console.log(myfunc(arrObj, 'title'));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors in your code. First keywords like `return`,`const`,`console` are all case sensative. Secondly you are not returning from the function. Third since property is a variable you have to use square braces instead of dot

```js
const myfunc = (arrObj, property) => {
  return arrObj.map(item => {
    return item[property]
  })
}

const arrObj = [{
    title: 'book',
    body: 'hello'
  },
  {
    title: 'cup',
    body: 'hii'
  }
];

// Func call
console.log(myfunc(arrObj, 'title'));
```